# Can potential energy exist in the absence of gravity?

Tags: energy

Can other forms of potential energy exist that use forces besides gravity, such as magnetism, or simply the pull provided by a moving body to which the object whose potential energy is being measured  is anchored?
What length should be substituted in place of the height between a surface and the body?

Comment: Electrostatic potential is a good example, but a mechanical spring will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are lots of potential energies, one for each different force you can imagine. Magnetic force is a good example, if you hold two magnets apart from each other with the north pole of one magnet directed toward the south pole of the other magnet, they will feel an attractive force (but it is not an inverse-square law force like gravity). You can define a potential energy for this force. If you let the magnets go, they'll move toward each other, reducing their potential energy and increasing kinetic energy just like with gravity.

The length question does not have a unique answer. You can define your position where potential energy = 0 as any position you like. With gravity, we normally put potential energy = 0 at the ground level, but you could put the zero at cloud level if you want. All this does is introduce a constant offset into the potential energy. Since only changes in potential energy create forces, and a constant never changes, it doesn't matter what the constant is.

In the case of the two magnets, you might want to choose the starting position as the zero point of potential energy. Then when the magnets move closer together, shrinking their distance by the distance L, then you measure L as the change from the starting position where L = 0. Alternatively, you could make the position where the two magnets touch to be the zero point. Then L is simply the distance between the two magnets. None of this make any difference to the change in potential energy caused by a *change* in position.

Comment: In astrophysics, on the other hand, we usually put potential energy zero at infinity. This makes all potential energies negative. Infinity is a good choice because it is not dependent on the dimensions of the system. This has two cheerful consequences: the total energy (kinetic+potential) of a circular orbit is half the [negative] potential energy of a point on the orbit. And the total energy of a parabolic orbit is exactly zero.